# Best design pattern for REST api based app in flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dart

Hi Flutter gurus and noobs there.

I was going through so many articles, videos and resources about getting an idea about different types of design patterns that can be used in a flutter project.

What I understood is that if the app relies on stream based API like in Firebase then it's good to adopt BLoC or RxDart.
If the app depends on state classes and event then it's good to adopt ChangeNotifier with provider or MobX. Please correct me if I miss something there.

Previously I have developed and app which depends on REST API's(with json data) and I used a much cleaner approach just using stateful/less widgets and managing the changes where needed.

No I would like to have a solid idea about my design pattern which I can confirmedly use. The app will solely based on REST API's and the API will have token based authentication. Having login, signup and all CRUD operations depended on REST API's what is the best design pattern I can adhere for the development.

Pleased if it can be explained and im being enlightened.
Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: Not sure its the "best" design pattern but here is what my team is doing: 
We use the package "DIO" for all http / api requests, this is working flawlessly you can use tokens (we use jwt).  
To pass the data in the app there is a cleaner approach than using solely statefull widgets and named it already: Provider. We use provider but as Riverpod is the successor of Provider I would take a look into that. It might be harder to understand in the beginning but you don't need a context to pass data around which will save you some trouble later. Hope it helped & I understood the question correctly

Comment: thank you so much for the generous comment @MiroLiebschner. you did understand what I was on about. I will look into this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no right or wrong answer to your question. If you ask three developers, you will probably get four different answers. I'd say you can use any [architecture style](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples) or design pattern which suites to your taste and requirements.

If you create an abstraction layer for the REST API (Layer 1), you could even switch to another architecture style without any change in Layer 1. Or the other way round, if you want to change your backend to Firebase or something else, you could provide another implementation of Layer 1 without any change in the frontend code (Layer 2). I'd call Layer 1 "services". The Dart API for those services should not leak out anything related to the HTTP protocol to Layer 2, but only use data types from your domain or the Dart SDK.

In that concept, the Service is an interface. The Widget has only a dependency on the interface. The actual implementation is provided to the Widget using [dependency injection](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/dependency-injection-in-dart-flutter-apps-3332f1a61041). Only the `main.dart` file knows which implementation should be used for the respective Service, and initializes the selected dependency injection mechanism accordingly. The Widget can then use any [state management library](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) and call the Service for reading and writing operations when necessary.

[image: uml diagram for dependency injection concept]

For the dependency injection of the Service into the Widget you can use e.g. [constructor injection](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/dependency-injection-in-dart-flutter-apps-3332f1a61041), [inherited widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html), [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it), or [global variables](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/blob/7115a936c0c1d9ca566fb9653aaf8a5574d113ae/packages/devtools_app/lib/src/globals.dart).

##### References

- [The Clean Architecture | Robert C. Martin (Uncle Bob)](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html)
- [Leaky Abstractions |
  Arvind Padmanabhan](https://devopedia.org/leaky-abstractions)

Comment: thank you jaunt for this detailed explanation. I can see there are few things that I need to learn and practice about as well. I think with the interface for the REST service comes from the approach used in Android with retrofit right ? ,

Comment: No, this design approach is influenced from what I am used to coming from Java/Spring.